# iOS Run Code Once a Day

Tags: ios, timer, background

The idea behind this app is very simple: download a file. However this app will be for people who are not always within internet access range, so I need it to know that at, say 9:00 AM, to download a file to the hard drive. There will be a button within the app to do it manually as well, but I've already got that working.

As I understand it, this will be difficult if it is even possible. I know that iOS doesn't like multitasking, but I am also aware that it does allow for background timer functions. I am open to any sort of suggestions anyone might have to accomplish this, even if it means writing a separate app. Thanks.

Edit: I see there is the possibility of working with Notifications, or even maybe the Calendar. Ideas in that category as also welcomed.

Edit 2: I also read something about an external server initiating an app, but it gave no description.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's the situation regarding background execution and notifications and timers etc. in relation to an app scheduling some activity to happen periodically.

1. An app cannot execute in the background unless:

   1. It requests extra time from the OS to do so. This is done using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`. It is not specified (intentionally) by Apple how long this extra time is, however in practice it is around 10 minutes.
   2. An app has a background mode, the modes are: voip, audio, location, newstand. Even if it has one of these types an app cannot execute without some restrictions. The rest of this discussion assumes the app does not have a background mode.
2. When an app is suspended it cannot do ANYTHING to rouse itself directly. It cannot previously have scheduled an NSTimer, it cannot make use of something like performSelector:afterDelay. etc.

   The ONLY way the app can become active again is if the USER does something to make it active. The user can do this from via of the following:

   1. Launch the app directly from its icon
   2. Launch the app in response to a local notification that was previously scheduled by the app while it was active.
   3. Launch the app in response to a remote notification sent by a server.
   4. A few others: such as URL launching if the app is registered to deal with launching via a url; or if its registered to be capable of dealing with a certain type of content.

If an app is in the foreground when a local/remote notification fires then the app receives it directly.

If the app is not currently in the foreground when a local/remote notification fires then the app DOES NOT receive it. There is no code that is executed when the notification fires!

Only IF the user selects the notification will the app become active and it can execute.

Note that the user can disable notifications, either for the entire device, or just for a specific application, in which case the user will never see them. If the device is turned off when a notification is due to fire then it is lost.

Comment: So choice c), I can have a server send out a request that will start the app. That sounds perfect. Do you know where I can go to learn about how that works?

Comment: Not quite, notice that c) is listed under: "The only way the app can become active again is if the user does something to make it active. The user can:". i.e. the app is not launched directly by the notification but by the user seeing the notification and clicking it. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

Comment: This is an answer one decade ago, with iOS 13 and BGTaskScheduler, are there more things iOS Apps can do in the background now?

Answer (score 2):

You could use local notifications. They execute code when the user opens the notification that is presented. You can set the local notification to recur at a specified interval (e.g. daily, hourly, weekly, etc). This still requires the user to open the app to get the process started.

[UILocalNotification Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Once the delegate method fires, you only get a few seconds to execute code. Register for a long running background task, and download whatever you need to do. If it can't finish downloading in the 10 minutes you get for the task, then you need to rethink your download strategy.

[Apple Multitasking and Backgrounding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

We are using this same concept on iOS apps where I work, so this will work if you set it up right.

**UPDATE**

For those curious how this will work, you just need to implement the UILocalNotification delegate methods. They inherit from the UIApplicationDelegate that should already be in place.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
// start your long running bg task here and update your file

}
```

** UPDATE 2 **

Martin H's answer is the most correct so far. But this begs the question, if the user never opens the app, what is the point of downloading data they are never going to see? A recurring local notification reminding them to open the app and update may be the best way, but still requires the user to interact with your app if they want it to remain current and up-to-date.

Comment: No way I could do that without the notification showing up then, right?

Comment: Oh, it seems I could use it to play a sound and run the code instead . . . that would work. A little ding whenever the file is downloaded.

Comment: @BillBurgess Can they really run some code?, How is this accomplished?

Comment: You will still end up showing the notificaion. You have the option to allow them to open the app or not, that is  up to you. You are trying to skirt around some Apple restrictions, so the only way to get around it is to play by the rules... but bend them as far as you can to get what you need. This method works, but may not work for you until you try it.

Comment: Notifications do not execute code when presented! If the user accepts the notification then the app becomes active. THis is not the same thing at all. If the app is active when the notification expires the app can act on it directly, if the app is not active it is presented to the user.

Comment: I've added an example. But @MartinH is right, if the user doesn't open the app, no code is executed. The notification will still remain active and fire again at the set interval... but no code can be executed unless they hit the accept/open button.

Answer (score 0):

Background applications have a set time limit (I believe 10 minutes, but don't quote me on that, it could be less) to complete whatever they are working on. You will not be able to use background tasks to do what you want.

What you can do is set an NSUserDefault with the date of the last download. On launch check the date saved, if the date is not the current date, and it is after 9:00am, initiate the download programatically.

Comment: "Don't quote me on that.". Yep, some apps have been known to run indefinitely.

Comment: That's the problem. This was supposed to be something that happens automatically, so they wouldn't have to remember to do something.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is not possible, at most what you can do is send push notifications to the user, so that they manually update when required.

Comment: No way for those notifications to also run some code with them?

Comment: @MarcelMarino I am afraid not.

Comment: They can run some code, but iOS gives "an application a limited time to run in the background" http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1

Comment: @LouFranco So based on that, unless I am mistaken, it seems like a calendar could be set to run a bit of code. Is that right? The code itself is very simple, takes an instant to run. The question is if I can set it to execute once a day, M-F (or everyday if that's easier).

Comment: Or did you mean the notification can only be set so far into the future?

Comment: It's not a Calendar -- it's called a Local Notification. You can set them to run at intervals and you get a limited time to run.

Comment: There's not necessarily a need to send a push notification (i.e. from a server), each time your code runs it could schedule a local notificaiton.

Comment: *Lou Franco* Your comment makes it sound like notifications themselves can run code. This is not the case, if the app is not active then the user will see the notification, if the user accepts that notification then the app will become active and then it gets the chance to execute. THis is not the same as the situation you describe. Also the limited time to run is nothing directly to do with notifications at all, that is orthogonal.

Comment: @MartinH So they could get a notification every 7:00 AM to run the app or not run the app, ostensibly? What if I turn off the iPad and the time for the notification passes, will the notification come on when I start the iPad up?

Comment: Marcel - Provided they haven't turned off notification alerts then yet. If the device is turned off when the notification is due to fire then it is lost.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the following?

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >=7.0)
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:600];


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```