# How do I cancel an iOS local notification after a particular time?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

I want to cancel an iOS local notification after a particular time.

For example : **a week later**

```
- (void)ViewDidLoad
{
    NSDate *date = [NSdate date];
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    //set some localNotif's properties
    localNotif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    localNotif.fireDate = date

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
}
```

How can I cancel `localNotif` after a week (7 days) and can you show me the code?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put that method. It will need to be called at some point while the user is within the app. And what do you mean 'when can you figure out the time'? You'd cancel whenever you know you want to cancel it.

Comment: What would you like to trigger the cancel? The user pressing a button? Closing the app?

Comment: @Christian ,I've add some codes there ,can you give me some advices ? thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that unless your app is running in the foreground at the time the notification is due to be cancelled (in which case there would be no need to cancel it anyway).

The reason you can't do it is because you would need a timer to tell you when to cancel it, and you can't schedule a timer unless you are an app that has a background mode, in which case you could schedule a timer to notify you - but even background apps can be suspended still it would not be guaranteed.

See here
[iOS Run Code Once a Day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903568/ios-run-code-once-a-day/10904172#10904172)

Comment: so you mean the only way to do that is "checking each time the app is running to see if it's time to cancel it" ?

Comment: Yes, but that is pointless, because when the app is in the foreground the app will directly receive the notification and not the user and so the app can just ignore it rather than cancel it.