# Schedule a Future Call to Trigger CloudKit Delete Record in MapKit App

Tags: ios, mapkit, cloudkit

I am currently working on a MapKit and CloudKit application. I allow the user to place custom pins but I want to delete those pins after a certain period of time. I am wondering if there is an easy way to trigger an event even if the application is running in the background.

NSTimer = Does not trigger in the background.

What are my options?

Comment: Try `performSelector: withObject:  afterDelay:`

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not get triggered when the app is running in the background mode! But Thanks!

Comment: Why not delete the pins when the application returns from the background?

Answer (score 0):

In CloudKit there is no server side logic. You can also not execute any code if your app is not active.

See the answer in the following question:
[iOS Run Code Once a Day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903568/ios-run-code-once-a-day)

If you really need the functionality you described, then you need an OS X app that is connected to the same CloudKit container. That app should query all data (once every .. minutes) and delete the pin data.

the sugestion from harryhorn probably would be the best way for your app to handle this.