# How do i run a code every day at a set time? Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I looked around but couldn't find any answers.

Anyone know how to run a block of code every day at 12:00 without using `NSTimer`?

Comment: You could schedule a local device notification without visible notification -- have code execute when it occurs?

Comment: silent push notification

Comment: brandon will that work?

Comment: Hopefully this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10904172/2368295

Answer (score 2):

You could setup a dispatch source to do this. Get the time remaining until noon as the start time and set the interval to every 24 hours. Something like:

```
let startTime = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().nextDateAfterDate(NSDate(), matchingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, options: .MatchNextTime) ?? NSDate()
let startDelta = startTime.timeIntervalSinceNow * NSTimeInterval(NSEC_PER_SEC)
let periodicSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, dispatch_get_main_queue())

dispatch_source_set_timer(periodicSource, dispatch_walltime(nil, Int64(startDelta)), 60 * 60 * 24 * NSEC_PER_SEC, NSEC_PER_SEC)
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(periodicSource) {
    print("bing bong!")
}
dispatch_resume(periodicSource)
```