# Is it possible to launch a short task every day at a specific time even if the ipad is in standby/sleep mode (for 4 hours or more)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, background-process, appdelegate

I have a function that is launch with that code at a specific time:
In my active viewcontroller.m:

```
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];

NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
[comps setDay:29];
[comps setMonth:5];
[comps setYear:2017];
[comps setHour:12];
[comps setMinute:47];
[comps setSecond:0];

NSDate *alarmDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]; // or @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a" if you prefer the time with AM/PM

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
[localNotification setRepeatInterval:NSCalendarUnitDay];
[localNotification setFireDate:alarmDate];
NSString *alarmStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:alarmDate];
[localNotification setAlertBody:alarmStr];
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

In the appDelegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    // check state here

    if(state == UIApplicationStateBackground )
    {
        NSLog(@"App in background...");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"App button shutdown...");
    }
    //if date is passed, no action
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *synchroDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString: notification.alertBody];

    NSDate *currentDate= [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"difference : %f", [synchroDate timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate]);

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSInteger comps = (NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond);

    NSDateComponents *date1Components = [calendar components:comps
                                                    fromDate: currentDate];
    NSDateComponents *date2Components = [calendar components:comps
                                                    fromDate: synchroDate];

    currentDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:date1Components];
    synchroDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:date2Components];

    BOOL result = [currentDate isEqual:synchroDate];
    if (result)
    {
         [self sendEmailAuto];
    }
}
```

I would like to put that code in background AND working even if the iPad is in stand by mode since a long time (hours and hours) for example. The task is just sending an email. (Is that the 10 minutes that are being mentioned everywhere is 10mn of the task during, or 10mn after the ipad begin to be in stand by mode ?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The app has to be opened by user when the device recieves a notification, other than that there is no way to do this! Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903568/ios-run-code-once-a-day

Comment: With that code, I just receive a notification on the iPad without any code execution. Is there any way to launch a code in background ? (I know that it is possible to launch code in background even if the app is in sleep mode)

Comment: If your app uses voip, audio, location, newstand etc then you can request for additional background execution time.It is strictly for those tasks only, if you perform any other tasks other than these, then your app will be rejected.

Comment: I just would like to send an email, even if the ipad is in sleep mode for 5 or 6 hours. (I don't want the app to be on the app store, so I am very free on that point :D)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS: How can I send an email automatically with an iPad in sleep mode every hours during X hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44263552/ios-how-can-i-send-an-email-automatically-with-an-ipad-in-sleep-mode-every-hour)