# How to call a method for one day delay even the app is killed in iOS?

Tags: ios, nstimeinterval, performselector

I want to call a method with the delay of one day even app is killed 
I tried with performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: method but the method is called when I app is alive

I don't know how to do that? can anyone help me?

Comment: Initially start the timer with one day time interval. Save the time stamp to _UserDefaults_ when the app is killed in other words, in _UIApplicationWillTerminate_ method in _AppDelegate_. When user open the app again, check the time difference between saved time and current time. If difference is greater than one day, then the associated call back will be fired.

Comment: perhaps take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904172/2237587